# What is a Residency Affidavit in the USA?

Tags: meaning

What is a Residency Affidavit in the USA and how does it differ from a Proof of Residency?

Comment: This looks more suitable for the [Law SE](http://law.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question of English, but law - https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think it is law per se.

Comment: Note that in an affidavit, you sign a statement in front of a notary public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further clarify Lambe’s answer and generalize to make it more useful to others:

An “affidavit” is a written statement *claiming* a fact (in this case, that you’re a resident) that you sign under penalty of perjury.  That means if someone can prove you lied, you could go to jail.

“Proof of residence” in this case would mean documentation *provided by someone else* that proves you qualify as a resident.  Two common examples would be rental leases or utility bills.

Generally, proof is superior to an affidavit (for everyone involved), and an affidavit is often only acceptable when it’s not possible to provide proof.

Comment: proof of residence is most definitely not provided by someone else. Only you can prove you live in a place with documents that show your name and your address. If you receive a light bill, that comes from the electric company but that company is not "proving" anything. You are.

Comment: @Lambie Would you prefer “created”?

Answer (score 0):

**Proof of Residence** would be something like a phone or light bill in your name at the address. Or a Driver's License with that address.

A **Residency Affidavit** is:

A form or statement that contains information about where you reside and which you swear is true. You attest to its truthfulness.

That said, the specifics would depend on the state.

Comment: This depends on jurisdiction and is better addressed law SE. If one asked "what is a noun" on law SE they might hear "a person, place or thing". One would get a much more comprehensive and here.

Comment: @jimm101 If a person like myself knows the answer from having interpreted in this subject matter, it's ok to post an answer. By the way, it does not depend on the jurisdiction. –

Comment: It doesn't? For taxes? For college tuition rates? It's very helpful for you to answer, but if someone is shopping for blueberries, it's rather unhelpful to keep one by the floor wax. :-)